# change the color of a border line depending on which section/div it is over

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

im trying to use jquery to make my border line change color depending on where it sits on the divs. i set position absolute and it is laying on both divs, so i was trying to make the line on the top div be the color grey and the line on the bottom div be white. i want to dynamically change depending on which section it is over.

https://codepen.io/asreenz/pen/MWpGMQO link to codepen

```js
var top1height = $(".top-box" ).height();
var bottom1height = $(".bottom-box" ).height(); 
 var linePosition = $(this).offset();
if(linePosition > top1height){
   $(".line").addClass(".line-grey"); 
   } 
else {
   $(".line").removeClass("line-grey"); 
   }
if(linePosition > bottom1height){
   $(".line").addClass(".line-white"); 
   } 
else {
   $(".line").removeClass("line-white"); 
   }
```

```css
.line{
  width:0px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -225px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-box{
  width:100vw;
  height:500px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.bottom-box{
  width:100vw;
  height:500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.line-grey{
  color:#8a96a3;
}
.line-white{
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="line">
    </div>
  <div class="top-box"></div>
  <div class="bottom-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the line to be fixed so that the two divs scroll under it and it can then change color? What is to happen when it is over both divs?

Comment: `$(".line").addClass(".line-grey");` should be `$(".line").addClass("line-grey");`

Comment: Maybe you want this? --> `$('.line').offset().top` will give you the offset off the top that your line is.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if your jquery code works but what I can tell is instead of using the "color" property you have to use "border-color". Like so :

```
.line-grey {
border-color: #8a96a3;
}

.line-white {
border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to change anything

Comment: i barely know jquery so if someone who is better than i can help that would be great haha

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the line should change its color whenever you scroll from box to box, then check this pen out.
https://codepen.io/ialexandru/pen/YzZvpBj

It's a bit more simple and works with unlimited boxes. All you should do is replace the line color from data attribute of each box.

I replaced the absolute position with fixed position just for you to see the transition easier.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="box" data-line-color="rgba(255,255,255,1)"></div>
   <div class="box" data-line-color="rgba(0,120,255,1)"></div>
   <div class="box" data-line-color="rgba(255,255,255,1)"></div>
   <div class="box" data-line-color="rgba(0,120,255,1)"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.line{
  width:0px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: .3s all;
}
.box{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
(function ($) {
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() / 2;
    $('.box').each(function() {
    if (scrollTop > $(this).offset().top) {        $('.line').attr('style','border-color: ' + $(this).data('line-color')); }
    });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this is so close to what i need, but when the line is going through each section i need the line/part of the line that touches the new section to change color. meaning like the second it enters whatever part of the line is touching, changes and whatever is still in the previous section is the same color, until it all goes into the new section.

Comment: **Check the code from the above URL now**. It should work just as you need. You don't need any script for this to work. The only requirement is that you need one fixed line for each box you have, each having the same position in the viewport. Also, the box needs to be clipped, so the lines could be visible only inside the box container - `overflow: hidden` won't work with fixed content.